# Why am I getting ROLLBACK_COMPLETE when trying to install OHDSI?

Tags: ohdsi-omop

I get the error message ROLLBACK_COMPLETE when I tried to install OHDSI-in-a-box from https://github.com/OHDSI/OHDSI-in-a-Box according to the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9JbgyE4rW2w.

I tried twice and both times I got ROLLBACK_COMPLETE instead of the message CREATE_COMPLETE.

What could be the problem ?